# Simple deploying on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I created my first node.js server app and I have deploying error on Heroku. In the log it says me that app successfully started, but I have "App Error" on heroku URL

Already checked my package.json and didn't found any troubles.

What I do wrong?

server.js:

```
'use strict';

const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {

    console.log(request.method, request.url);
    if (request.url == '/style.css'){
        const css = fs.readFileSync('style.css', 'utf8');
        response.end(css);
    }else{
        const html = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf8');
        response.end(html);
    }
});
console.log('port = ', process.env.PORT);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
console.log('Server Started, yay!');
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Enigma",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

and Heroku log:

```
 -----> Node.js app detected
-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 6.x...
       Downloading and installing node 6.11.4...
       Using default npm version: 3.10.10
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
-----> Building dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)
-----> Caching build
       Clearing previous node cache
       Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
       - node_modules
       - bower_components (nothing to cache)
-----> Build succeeded!
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types     -> (none)
       Default types for buildpack -> web
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 15M
-----> Launching...
       Released v11
       https://enigma-test.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

Comment: is it working locally...???

Comment: Yep, perfectly on localhost

Comment: what does http://localhost:3000/ shows??

Comment: It shows test index.html page with simple <h2> tag in the body

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are missing the `Procfile`, which contains:

```
web: node .
```

I successfully deployed your application at enigma-test-2 (I have now deleted the app from my account)

You can find a complete copy of the project I deployed here, that employes exactly your code: [Repo](https://gist.github.com/MatteoRagni/2be84fbece541e2f3f324b3cd8fd4b00)

Once you cloned the gist:

```
git clone https://gist.github.com/MatteoRagni/2be84fbece541e2f3f324b3cd8fd4b00 enigma-test
```

you may want to deploy it:

```
heroku login
# make your login

cd enigma-test
heroku git:remote -a enigma-test-2

# make your modifications

git commit -am "commit for heroku"
git push heroku master
```

You should see your application on heroku now.

Comment: I cloned your repo and now it works

Very strange.

Thank you very much

Comment: I created Procfile, but it not worked with my own repo. Only in your repo :)

Comment: Ah ok. Then maybe there was a simple mistype in the Procfile? Maybe some non printable character? Or it was not in UTF-8 encoding?

Comment: I found a problem. It very funny, but i just renamed "Server.js" to "server.js" and now it works. ;D

Comment: Ahahaha... It happens... To avoid the problem, since you are using the `package.json`, you can simply put a `web: node .` to run the correct binary.

Answer (score 1):

We need to tell Heroku how to run our app. Just create a new file called Procfile with this content:

```
web: node server.js
```

and then try to deploy the code again & then a heroku restart

```
heroku restart --app application_name
```

Comment: You answered correctly first. Let's upvote the fastest ;)